# getting to know If u switch the tabs of UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have situation like
I have a UITabBarController. It has 3 tabs each having a UISplitViewController. Now 0th tab is selected. if I switch the tab (i.e from 0th to 1st),and then I switch back (i.e from 1st to 0th). So Please suggest me a way to find that My 0th's Tab UISplitViewController needs to know that the control is back to it's Tab.

Comment: `viewWillAppear` for the `UITableViewController` will be called when it becomes active.

Comment: Thanks @UditS
Thats the simplest way. Please put it as answer. so that we can make an answer for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `viewWillAppear` for the `UITableViewController` of the 0th tab (or any suitable tab). This will be called when it becomes active.

Answer (score 0):

You need implement UITabBarControllerDelegate methods 
 
`- tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` for more details please look [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/)